# Finding sum of empty columns in a row

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to create a column which finds count of non empty columns in a postgres table (like given below). Can u give me a head's up or a solution?

[image]

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not as images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Postgres, I would simply do:

```
select t.*,
       ((a is not null)::int + (b is not null)::int + (c is not null)::int) as cnt
from t;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use GENERATED always as column. Example:

```
create table test (a VARCHAR (50),
b VARCHAR (50),
c VARCHAR (50),
cnt numeric GENERATED always as  (

  case when  a is null then 0 else 1 end +
  case when  b is null then 0 else 1 end +
  case when  c is null then 0 else 1 end
) STORED);
```

Link: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fU5LLuh5gvwkKhhRbeCyh8/0

Comment: ... or just use the same expression in a query.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to hard-code the column names, you can use some JSON magic for this:

```
select a,b,c, 
       (select count(*) from jsonb_object_keys(jsonb_strip_nulls(to_jsonb(t)))) as num_not_null
from the_table t
```

`jsonb_strip_nulls(to_jsonb(t))` converts the whole row into a single json value where the column names are the keys. Any null value will be removed. Then the keys are extracted using `jsonb_object_keys` and the number of keys returned is the number of non-null columns in that row.

Using a CASE expression as shown in EragonBY's answer or the boolean expressions in Gordon's answer will be a lot faster if you don't mind explicitly listing all column names.

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=d59671e8a9546484bfe6892d80758eb4)